# How do I implement asynchronous read operations in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a database set up with php code to write and read from it.  I want to allow multiple read operations to be executed in parallel.  I read the MySQL docs on synchronous vs. asynchronous operations, but I am still unclear on how to do this, or if its even necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? My assumption is that you have an outer query with a loop and nested query per iteration; if this is the case then just look into `JOIN`s. Implementing asynchronous queries requires separated PHP threads and connections.

Comment: PHP was designed to be synchronous, mysqli supports partial async where it doesn't block but it can't run two queries at the same time.  async can be nice for a single request's performance but it usually doesn't make a noticeable difference in a busy server when you have multiple requests running in parallel.

Comment: @Phiter That duplicate has nothing to do with this question. Atomic transaction instructions are still executed in sequence, not in parallel.